# Sync local postgres database with server postgres database?

Tags: django, postgresql

Currently, I have a PostgreSQL database running on my local server, and everything is functioning well. Now, I want to synchronize this local database with another database on a remote server but only in a specific schema.

There are two scenarios to consider:

Case I:
When an internet connection is available, I need the synchronization to occur immediately between the local and remote databases.

Case II:
In the absence of an internet connection, I want to store all changes in the local server. Once the internet connection becomes available, the system should automatically transfer all the unsynchronized data from the local server to the remote server.

I need guidance on the best approach to achieve this synchronization considering both cases.

Comment: As long as the synchronization is one way, use logical replication. Stay away from two-way replication.